# JS Функция перестает работать при удалении из неё console.log()

Tags: javascript, функции

Написал функцию для преобразования названия месяца в его порядковый номер. Но функция почему-то перестает работать (возвращает undefined), если удалить из неё console.log(). Не могу понять, почему это происходит и как вообще консоль.лог может влиять на работоспособность кода?

```
let months = ["январь", "февраль", "март", "апрель", "май", "июнь", "июль", "август", "сентябрь", "октябрь", "ноябрь", "декабрь"];

let monthID = prompt("Название или номер месяца?").toLowerCase();

function formatMonth (mon) {
  if ((mon).toString().length > 2) {
  mon = months.indexOf(mon) + 1; 

  } else 
  console.log(); // Если убрать эту строку, функция перестает работать
  return mon;
}

alert("Этот месяц идет по счету " + formatMonth(monthID));
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что я понимаю, почему код некорректен, (mon не возвращается если if дает true, плюс ошибка в синтаксисе else - нету фигурных скобок), но вопрос состоит в том, почему этот некорректный код срабатывает если в нем присутствует console.log() ?

Comment: Вам уже два человека объяснили - почему. Потому что когда отрабатывает блок под `if`, функция ничего не возвращает при закомментированном `console.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличный пример почему после `if` и `else` стоит всегда выражение брать в скобки.

```
} else 
  console.log(); // Если убрать эту строку, функция перестает работать
return mon;
```

В данном виде `console.log()` выполнятся в блоке `else`.

```
} else 
return mon;
```

Теперь в блоке `else` выполняется `return mon`, а значит результат возвращается **только** если исходное выражение в `if` - ложно.

В данном случае достаточно просто убрать `else`, так как в этом блоке ничего не происходит.

Либо добавить скобки вокруг блока:

```
else {
  console.log(); // Если убрать эту строку, функция перестает работать        
}
return ...
```

В этом случае убрав строку с `console.log` в `else` останется просто пустой блок.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в целом всё прояснилось! То есть else при отсутствии фигурных скобок обрабатывает только следующую после него команду? Получается, если есть консоль.лог - он попадает в else, и "вытесняет" оттуда return. Но если его убрать, return попадет в else и не будет выполнен в случае если if даст true?

Comment: @Дмитрий, именно так и написано в ответе. `else` **всегда** "обрабатывает" только следующую "команду". Команда может быть одним выражением либо составным, обернутым в скобки

Answer (score 1):

```
} else {
  console.log(); // Если убрать эту строку, функция продолжает работать
}
return mon;
```

Когда Вы комментируете `console.log();` в Вашем коде, `return mon;` попадает в `else`.